# Matlab matrix index transform

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, indexing, vectorization

Suppose I have a Matlab matrix `A(x,y)` which is square matrix with size N+1.

I want a new matrix `B`, whose element `B(x,z)` is `A(x,N-x-z)`, and in case x+z>N, `B(x,z)` is just zero.

Of course I can do it using a 2-level for loop, but for the sake of performance, **I want to know if there is a 'vectorized' method to finish this job.**

**Edit 1**:

All indices mention above start from 0.

**Edit 2**:

If the indices start from 1 instead of 0, the question can reformulated as follows:

I have a Matlab matrix `A(i,j)` which is a square matrix with size N+1.

I want a new matrix `B`, whose element `B(i,k)` is `A(i,N+3-i-k)`, and in case `i+k>N+2`, `B(i,k)` is just zero.

Comment: Do you define indices `x` and `z` starting at 1 or at 0?

Comment: @wdg How can indices start from `0` in MATLAB?

Comment: @LuisMendo, they start from 0. Matlab's start-from-1 convention always gives me headache... I have changed the question accordingly.

Comment: @wdg What about the case `x+z=N`? Can you give sample input-output?

Comment: If the matrix is size N, and the indices start from zero, then N-x-z is going to give an index outside the matrix for x==z==0.  You might rewrite the whole question in terms of indices that start from 1, since you are going to have do that in the end anyway.

Comment: @Divakar, please see my Edit 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping this is what you are looking for -

```
N = size(A,1)

B = A

B(fliplr(triu(ones(N)))~=1)=NaN
B = fliplr(B)

[~,col1] = sort(~isnan(B),2,'descend')
row1 = repmat(1:N,N,1)'; %%//'
restructured_indices = sub2ind(size(B),row1(:),col1(:))
B = reshape(B(restructured_indices),N,N)
B(isnan(B))=0
```

**Version 2:**

```
N = size(A,1)

col1 = bsxfun(@minus,repmat(N:-1:1,N,1),[0:N-1]');%%//'
row1 = repmat([1:N]',1,N) %%//'

valid_ind = find(col1>0);
col1 = col1(valid_ind);
row1 = row1(valid_ind);

ind2 = sub2ind(size(A),row1(:),col1(:))

B= zeros(size(A));
B(valid_ind)= A(ind2)
```

**Version 2 (Shorter Form):**

```
B = zeros(size(A));
N = size(A,1)

col1 = bsxfun(@minus,repmat(N:-1:1,N,1),[0:N-1]') %%//'
remapped_ind = bsxfun(@plus,N.*(col1-1),[1:N]') %%//'

normal_ind = 1:N*N;
B(normal_ind(remapped_ind>0)) = A(remapped_ind(remapped_ind>0))
```

Comment: Your code does give the correct results, but your method is more elaborate than I expected...

Comment: @wdg Check out Version 2 (Shorter Form).